# How can I translate "Read More" on Drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have installed the internationalization module, but can't find where to specify a translation for "Read more" and other system strings.
Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have added and enabled another language in `admin/config/regional/language`

Just head over to `admin/config/regional/translate` and search for the string you want translated.

**IMPORTANT** The strings are both case and whitespace sensitive. Searching for "Read More" returns no results but "read more" has a hit (see screenshot).

Also, since a lot of strings have placeholders that are substituted with variables you might have better luck with other strings if you search for a small subset of it as opposed to the entire thing!

Additionally, I **strongly** recommend installing the [Localization Update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module, it will automatically download and update translations for all contributed modules.

[image: Attached Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I tried to search for "read more" in the "translate" tab (the only place where I can search for strings) but there were no result.

Comment: Nevermind, I did not update translations correctly, now it's working. Thanks